# Как сделать приложение и не нарушить политику Google?)

Tags: android, google-play

Сделал приложение для сайта.

Соответственно данные при регистрации/входе или данные о заказе отправляются и хранятся в бд на хостинге.

Также есть два WebView.
Одно ссылка на телегу.
Втрое на пополнение баланса(Почему то открывается в браузере)

Гугл ругает "не соответствует одной или нескольких нашим политикам программы разработчиков"

Что не нравиться гуглу и какие варианты решения есть?

Ps: Политика конфиденциальности указана только виде ссылки в консоле(Если это на что-то влияет)
Возможно и на экран с регистрацией стоит запихнуть)

[image: Соглашение о распространении ПО]

Comment: Сделать приложение и не нарушить какое-то правило - невозможно. Так уж правила написаны и так уж модерация работает. Вообще, судя по описанию - ваше приложение ничего кроме WebView не содержит и это, вроде, по правилам - препятствие публикации, ибо в таком случае можно просто сайтом ограничиться.

Comment: Попробуйте аппеляцию подать/выпустить новую версию/перепсать приложение так, чтобы было что-то в нём кроме WebView, если в нём только оно. Но надеяться на адекватность модерации у гугла не стоит.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В приложение есть активити с 3 фрагментами(Приветственное, регистрация, вход) 
Второе активити с 5 фрагментами 2 из которых вебвью
Фрагмент формирования заказа и его отправки
Фрагмент Истории заказов

Comment: Тогда, видимо, не в WebView дело. Может у вас какие-то либы подключены, которые как-то в сеть лезут не так? Рекламные SDK или аналитика какая-то? Подробностей от гугла никаких нет? И/или может сайт, который в WebView открывается какой-то зловред содержит?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Могу в принципе скрины приложения выложить. Вебвью на фрикассу и на телегу. Фрикассу в браузере открывает, а не в приложении.
Еще пишут Мы нашли проблему в следующей области (ы):
Title (ru_RU):... (Но я так понял это просто название выпуска)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я думаю проблема в том что моё приложение открывает браузер или то что нету пользовательского соглашения при регистрации

Comment: К сожалению, я ничем вам помочь тут не смогу) Надо выяснять у гугла что не так и как исправить

Comment: "Политика Google Play строго запрещает публиковать .... и другие приложения, которые недопустимым образом используют ресурсы сети или устройства, а также персональные данные." правильное хранение и отправка??? https://play.google.com/intl/ru/about/developer-content-policy/

Comment: @MarkCain Спасибо за ссылку! Что значит правильное хранение и отправка?
Я только почту требую и пароль придумать...

Comment: @Alexander, я о том что, например, пароли в чистом виде не храним. Подробнее например тут: https://habr.com/ru/company/acribia/blog/413157/ Иначе попадаем под "Нарушение конфиденциальности".

Comment: @MarkCain Спасибо, поробую)

Comment: @MarkCain а хэшировать я так понял надо в приложение и уже хэш отправлять на сервер?

Comment: @Alexander чаще только на стороне сервера (там же проходит валидация) и уже зашифрованные отправляют в БД.

Comment: @MarkCain опять отклонили... По той же ошибки. Добавил функцию хэша на клиент и на сервер...Где вообще можно приложение протестировать кроме гугла?